# Kitniot – Minhag Italia

Tags: minhag, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, italy

What is the Italki minhag with regards to kitniot? As they have historically been at a crossroads between the Ashkenazi and Sephardi worlds,* it is often less cut-and-dry now, due to the loss of many minhagim.

---

*per some opinions, the Rheinland communities descend from Italian kehillot

Comment: It's a very interesting question and like you say, may need to be determined by the specific community you are looking at. Minhag Venice and Minhag Rome are two that come to mind. Fano would be another place to look. There are minhagim associated with Livorno, Capri and Elba too.

Comment: According to this link the communities of Livorno and Elba were largely Sephardim. http://www.msacerdoti.it/elbaebreipreziosiinglese.pdf

Comment: shibole haleket, piske harid, ... maharik, Bartenura, are italianim. I searched  in a site of italian minhag and did not found.

Comment: @Yaacov livorno is largely seph, but in Italy there was always 3 cpmmunities in each city.

Answer (score 1):

The Italkim eat kitniyot. The discussed kitniyot ban originated from the communities around the Rhine valley. For the Passover week rice takes the place of pasta in the Roman community (I lived there for years and know well the local customs). The Italian rabbis would fully agree with the chahchamim Yerucham ben Meshullam, Shmuel me'Plaize and Ba'al ha'Turim who spoke against the ban.

Answer (score 1):

While there are definitely many different communities within Italy, according to my grandfather z"l, the Minhag of K"K Milano was to eat Kitniyos, including rice, on Pesach.

For further reading, see [this article](http://www.responsafortoday.com/vol3/4.pdf) which quotes Italian Rabbis through the ages.